# Find non-case sensitive string in a mixed list of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, searching

Consider an example list with mixed element types, e.g.:

```
list = { 1.234 , a[2] , {"Abc" , 4/5} , "acb" };
```

I would like to have a function that finds the position of a string, without regard to upper or lower characters, e.g.:

```
findPosition[list,"abc"]
```

> {{3,1}}

Is there a function like that in Mathematica? Or maybe one can implement it with efficient performance?

EDIT:

My current workaround is:

```
findPosition[list_,str_]:=Position[list/.x_String:>ToLowerCase[x],ToLowerCase[str]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that `StringMatchQ[]` has the `IgnoreCase` option:

```
Position[{1.234, a[2], {"Abc", 4/5}, "acb"},
         s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "abc", IgnoreCase -> True]]
   {{3, 1}}
```

Comment: Decided to go with this answer after all, since it is minimal, as all it does is a query -- no operations on the data.

Answer (score 4):

```
Position[list, s_String /; ToLowerCase[s] == "abc"]
```

> {{3, 1}}

or

```
Position[list, s_String?(EqualTo["abc"]@*ToLowerCase)]
```

Comment: I like how this does not need to make substitutions in `list` itself to search it!

Comment: `Position[ToLowerCase[list], "abc"]` also works.

Comment: The rationale behind using a `_String` pattern is to pre-filter with a very inexpensive test: This ensures that only few expressions are actually fed to `ToLowerCase`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that ToLowerCase does not evaluate if the input is not a string, but it is Listable, so it will thread over your list:

```
list = {1.234, a[2], {"Abc", 4/5}, "acb"};
ToLowerCase[list]

(* Out: {ToLowerCase[1.234], ToLowerCase[a[2]], {"abc", ToLowerCase[4/5]}, "acb"} *)
```

That should not bother you though; it certainly does not bother `Position`:

```
Position[ToLowerCase[list], "abc"]
(* Out: {{3, 1}} *)
```